# Is there any performance issue related to using arrow function in React Effect Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React introduced Hooks in their latest proposal. The Effect Hook takes a function and an array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `${unRead} notifications`
}, [unRead])
```

React is [intentional using an arrow function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#detailed-explanation). This means that a new function is created every time the Effect Hook is called.

Does this have any effect on the performance, considering the fact that a component can have many Effect Hooks?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to benchmark and find out. That said, I'm 90% sure V8 will be able to cache that function by its input and return signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that a new function is created every time the Effect Hook is called.

So is created a new array, `[unRead]`. This is not a problem neither for an array nor for a function. Similarly to other objects, functions are created very fast in modern JS engines. The performance impact of newly created function is negligible.

There can be some performance improvements if a function is reused, depending on the engine:

```
// outside a component
const effect = () => {...};

...
// inside a component
useEffect(effect);
```

vs

```
useEffect(() => {...});
```

But since effects often rely on enclosing scope (e.g. `useState` state), the reuse of effect functions may be impractical.

Regarding *arrow* functions, no performance differences are expected between arrow and regular functions, though arrows may have performance problems in some engines (e.g. older Firefox versions).

> Does this have any effect on the performance, considering the fact that a component can have many Effect Hooks?

If component function is called often enough to cause performance issues, this is the actual problem.